# Tensorflow QNA model in node.js returns empty array

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have followed https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/qna setup:

```
      require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
      const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
      const QNA = require('@tensorflow-models/qna');
    
      await tf.ready();
      let model = await QNA.load();
      console.log('\n\n model loaded');
    
      let answers = await model.findAnswers(question, text);
```

yet it always returns empty array as answer, even with [text sample](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/mobilebert-qna/index.html) from demo web page.

What I am doing wrong?

Edit: tensorflow v.2.3.0, QNA v.1.0.0 node.js v.12.12.0, on windows10 professional

Same behavior with tensorflow v.1.5.2 which is specifed as dependency in QNA, and which is used in working browser demo. Same thing with all available backend engines (cpu, wasm, native node)

As a matter of fact, demo from github repository does not yield answers, while the one on google for the same text and same question yields.

So, is there some place from where the code that runs on google can be downloaded?

Comment: While I have not solved the problem, there is a point in the github history that contains runing demo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/244d4cdc6eee673ab1d03baccdb06db26bde86fa So, perhaps one can start using it from that point.

Comment: I have successfully got it working on my local & as of now its in a bad shape .ie. you have to ask the exact same question and a very straight forward question for it to answer correctly

Answer (score 0):

While it is dirty, for those who want to use this model without delving into the what and why caused the problem, procedure is as follows:

1. Download zip from https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/244d4cdc6eee673ab1d03baccdb06db26bde86fa
2. Extract qna folder and open terminal/command shell in it
3. yarn install
4. cd demo
5. yarn install
6. yarn watch

- it will generate demo/node_modules/@tensorflow-models/qna folder under "qna" root.

7. cd node_modules/@tensorflow-models/qna
   Use "dist" folder found there as distribution instead of @tensorflow-models/qna

Also, a hint: download from  https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/mobilebert/1 ".JS" tab distribution of trained model data (it's 100Mbytes when unzipped) and use it from local disk. It will drastically reduce model loading time (from more than 90 seconds to 3 seconds)

```
let folder = process.cwd();
// load from local file takes about 3260 ms
let model = await QNA.load({modelUrl: 'file://'+ folder +'/mobilebert/model.json'});
```